# For an F# Type Provider, how do I do a binding redirect for a dependent assembly?

Tags: f#, type-providers, assembly-binding-redirect

I'm working on an F# Type Provider that has a dependency on FParsec 0.9.2.0. It depends on FSharp.Core 4.0.0.0. When I try to use the F# Type Provider, I get this error:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
> LOG: DisplayName = FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a (Fully-specified)
> LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
> Calling assembly : FParsec, Version=0.9.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e5c8267bb3bd1265.

I tried adding a `Froto.Gen.dll.config` and a `FParsec.dll.config`, both that had this in it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

No luck. Any ideas? My next plan of action is to build a new `FParsec.dll`, but that isn't always going to work.

Comment: Dll's don't have config files.  Try putting the redirects in the config for the exe that uses your DLL (or in your machine.config).

Comment: I'm using the type provider from another dll. For this particular situation, I just created a different build of FParsec. Asking people to modify their machine.config to use your type provider is probably not very practical.

Comment: @CameronTaggart: Have you tried putting the bindingRedirect into an fsc.exe.config (out of curiosity, mainly)? May be more practical than machine.config.

Comment: That config helped me run F# code in a C# NUnit project, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried overriding AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve and doing an explicit Assembly.LoadFrom on the location of FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0 when args.Name requires 4.0.0.0?

Comment: Here is an example from Tao Lio on how to do this: http://apollo13cn.blogspot.com/2012/07/self-notetype-provider-assembly-resolve.html

Answer (score 2):

You can actually define your own assembly resolver in your type provider.

If you override the `ResolveAssembly` method you can provide your own assembly resolution scheme.  The default implementation is fairly simple:

```
default this.ResolveAssembly(args) = 
    let expectedName = (AssemblyName(args.Name)).Name + ".dll"
    let expectedLocationOpt = 
        probingFolders 
        |> Seq.map (fun f -> IO.Path.Combine(f, expectedName))
        |> Seq.tryFind IO.File.Exists
    match expectedLocationOpt with
    | Some f -> Assembly.LoadFrom f
    | None -> null
```

Also you can add a probing path to influence the locations that are checked for assembly resolution:

```
[<TypeProvider>] 
type MyProvider(config: TypeProviderConfig) as this = 
    inherit TypeProviderForNamespaces()
    do this.RegisterProbingFolder "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/"
    ...
```